# Where can i get local merkle-patricia-tree root of my chain for look it in Nodejs?

Tags: private-blockchain, nodejs, merkle-patricia-tries, leveldb

In addition to [my prev question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/how-open-local-ethereum-chain-leveldb-using-nodejs-levelup-package)...

So i want to get data from my local chain. For that i use [example form wanderer.github.io](https://wanderer.github.io/ethereum/nodejs/code/2014/05/21/using-ethereums-tries-with-node/). I open my chain and get raw data, so this data, according to example - just raw node from chain. Next i need to see value of keys in that node. To do that i understood: all keys hidden in the bottom of a merkle-patricia-tree.

Let's speak about my problem. I want to do like in github: open my local wallet and look info about it, for that i looked at example:

```
//the genesis state root
var root = '12582945fc5ad12c3e7b67c4fc37a68fc0d52d995bb7f7291ff41a2739a7ca16';
var trie = new Trie(db, root);

//gav's address
var gav = new Buffer('8a40bfaa73256b60764c1bf40675a99083efb075', 'hex');

trie.get(gav, function (err, val) {
  var decoded = rlp.decode(val);
  console.log(decoded);
});
```

and wrote my own code with the fixes problem `Invalid root length. Roots are 32 bytes`:

```
var root = new Buffer('e5be92145a301820111f91866566e3e99ee344d155569e4556a39bc71238f3bc', 'hex'), 
    wallet = new Buffer('234132b22de7037e50b9fc4ebd7476315647869e', 'hex');

// work normally and get tree
var trie = new Trie(db, root);

trie.get(

    // what need to view
    wallet,

    // function which work with wallet info
    function (err, value)
    {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(value);

        var decoded = rlp.decode(value);
        console.log(decoded);
    }
);
```

It's work, but not get info. I didn't find `root` in my local chain like in example:

```
//the genesis state root
var root = '12582945fc5ad12c3e7b67c4fc37a68fc0d52d995bb7f7291ff41a2739a7ca16';
var trie = new Trie(db, root);
```

Anybody, **let's help Dora to find the right root of local chain** which be correct. Here my 0, 1 and last blocks from chain - maybe it will help you:

`debug.printBlock(0)`

> "Block(#0): Size: 507.00 B {
>   MinerHash: e521eab0c63dfd8bc7c6007e8b2ce954a66f9df3ab72ccf059e5aa49aeb149d8
>   Header(e5be92145a301820111f91866566e3e99ee344d155569e4556a39bc71238f3bc):[ParentHash:    0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   UncleHash:    1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347
>   Coinbase:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   Root:    9178d0f23c965d81f0834a4c72c6253ce6830f4022b1359aaebfc1ecba442d4e
>   TxSha    56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421
>   ReceiptSha:    56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421
>   Bloom:    00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   Difficulty:131072
>   Number:0
>   GasLimit:4712388
>   GasUsed:0
>   Time:0
>   Extra:
>   MixDigest:      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   Nonce:000000000000002a]
>   Transactions:[]
>   Uncles:[]
>   }"

`debug.printBlock(1)`

> "Block(#1): Size: 536.00 B {MinerHash: d8cebba1edfdd6f0364183ace1c5bdd8b5efb2999068aa8084c84043c4a5eb5e Header(3ab5cb6c29e583c50b90e413dca4a6df802d87dd0eb9569dff926f856d011375):[ParentHash:    e5be92145a301820111f91866566e3e99ee344d155569e4556a39bc71238f3bc UncleHash:    1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347 Coinbase:    234132b22de7037e50b9fc4ebd7476315647869e Root:    9c12c460f11fcf78d993119e08727e3e45266b3287e68fd42ef90bc730d275f6 TxSha    56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421 ReceiptSha:    56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421 Bloom:    00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Difficulty:    131072 Number:    1 GasLimit:    4712388 GasUsed:    0 Time:    1511614605 Extra:    \u0603\x01\a\x02�geth�go1.9.2�darwin MixDigest:      1d51851bf1fca11a0e670fb359b7420f1393074c8c2f1760edfa3a638652a7f7 Nonce:    33c0052eafe0f837] Transactions:[] Uncles:[]}"

`> debug.printBlock(81)`

> "Block(#81): Size: 536.00 B { MinerHash: 5fc817cc85c1ca755186f81e7a96699b68e43e53dc834a529de53bb8adcccaad Header(0dc9b40ee5b8039f2caad3542289000b22319aba762ae854208e3c73c7a31954): [ ParentHash:    d9e010a5154b44cd18706decb2d47b739c71d83e4b9b53d2d14d19b6aa423001 UncleHash:    1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347 Coinbase:    234132b22de7037e50b9fc4ebd7476315647869e Root:    2aeb24f3daa4f2ed2accc00ca9af287784cc9f7292bb1bc42641490f56e235e2 TxSha    56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421 ReceiptSha:    56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421 Bloom:    00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Difficulty:    132928 Number:    81 GasLimit:    4712388 GasUsed:    0 Time:    1511643645 Extra:    \u0603\x01\a\x02�geth�go1.9.2�darwin MixDigest:      486a097820216125cfe87aa9e8f67b7f64b51591026db5e205aec9e8bf4f1d5e Nonce:    21ac7e333ca8a7c4 ] Transactions: [] Uncles: [] } "

I tried to use genesis as root, but that not work:

> "0xe5be92145a301820111f91866566e3e99ee344d155569e4556a39bc71238f3bc"

Comment: Hmm. Try `d7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544` as the genesis state root, and see if that works.

Comment: Tried: it must be 32 bytes: `AssertionError: Invalid root length. Roots are 32 bytes`. Where did you get it?

Comment: also can give you my local chain if it need

Comment: Hold on - are you using the public chaindata, or is it a private network?

Comment: online, private not public

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69304/discussion-between-gudsaf-and-richard-horrocks).

Comment: Just to check: you mean you have created your own private network, with its own nodes? Or you mean you have created your own node that's running on the public network, which you've downloaded the chaindata for?

Comment: first variant: "created your own private network, with its own nodes"

Comment: Ah, ok, in that case your state root will be different - the one I posted was the public chain state root. Let me think how to get your root...

Comment: Okay, I think you can use Geth's `dump` feature, and pipe it to `head`. So something like `geth  dump  0  | head`

Comment: look now how to make it with local chain, also public is as you said: `d7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544`

Comment: The same command should work on a local chain (as long as you're using Geth).

Comment: got it, now look in Nodejs

`geth dump 0 --datadir "/Users/User/EthereumTestNet/" | head`
...
    "root": "9178d0f23c965d81f0834a4c72c6253ce6830f4022b1359aaebfc1ecba442d4e",
...

Comment: Great - that should be it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Geth's `dump` command to grab block `0`, and then grab the top part of the output:

```
$ geth  dump  0  | head
INFO [11-26|19:58:18] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/richard/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
INFO [11-26|19:58:18] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/richard/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [11-26|19:58:18] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/richard/.ethash               count=2
INFO [11-26|19:58:18] Loaded most recent local header          number=18048 hash=a57baa…6c2b4d td=8705769076450279
INFO [11-26|19:58:18] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0     hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [11-26|19:58:18] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=18048 hash=a57baa…6c2b4d td=8705769076450279
{
    "root": "d7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544",
    "accounts": {
        "000d836201318ec6899a67540690382780743280": {
            "balance": "200000000000000000000",
            "nonce": 0,
            "root": "56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
            "codeHash": "c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470",
            "code": "",
            "storage": {}
```

The first `root` should be the hash of the state root.

(If your chaindata is in a non-standard place you'll need to use the `--datadir` flag as well.)

Comment: Got it, and looked info in local private chain. So this accounts = local wallets, but if look at Mist number of wallet != account hash. for example i has wallet `0xf032868db0633790166e3d6282914e48E4d908c7` with 12 eth, i got it after mining, i want to look that wallet in dump, but not see it, just  wallet 

"9d373a0f53648a114f3fbc92ce8d144d05f71ab0": {
            "balance": "12000000000000000000",
            "root": "56e81f.."
        }

why that?