# How can i read transation data from ethereum to file or database?

Tags: database

I want read transations data "input" field from ethereum to file.How can i do it?thanks.

Comment: Geth uses LevelDB as storage, you can look at several similar questions https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/what-is-the-composition-of-the-blockchain-database, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/how-open-local-ethereum-chain-leveldb-using-nodejs-levelup-package how to interpret that data. IMHO the best source of information about that is the go-ethereum source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a node script and using web3.js in it.
Create an instance of the contract and using that instance use call the get methods.
Then write that data to the database or make/open a file and write it there.
Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given a transaction hash, you can call `eth_getTransactionByHash` on any node. Here's an example of getting the `input` from a transaction via [Etherscan's proxy API](https://etherscan.io/apis#proxy):

$ http get 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0x71027a0605ac52827e3a13700898cc54cb6a69e320dca637a82ada30497c45be&apikey=YourApiKeyToken' | jq -r .result.input
0x0a3b0a4f000000000000000000000000d485137c45a968e7fee9249485ff07493c574d71